# Poor speech recognition in WebChat control using token

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have a problem with speech recognition in BotFramework's [WebChat control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). I'm using token authentication ([Option 4 in link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/speech/index.html)), but the speech recognition is very poor. (It's not using my LUIS priming etc. I'm struggling even with saying 'hi'). Speech recognition in the testing panel in dev.botframweork.com is working very well, I want to achieve something similar.

EDIT:

My code (more or less, without additional conditions etc.)

```js
var botSettings = {
    user: {
        id: 'You'
    },
    resize: 'detect',
    webSocket: 'true'
};

if (result.chatToken) { // From URI, working fine, included just for the sake of it
    const botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
            token: result.chatToken.token
        });
    botSettings.botConnection = botConnection;
}

function get(url) { // URL is pointing to my API
    return fetch(url, {
         method: 'GET'
    }).then(res => res.text());
}

speechOptions = {
    speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({
        fetchCallback: () => get(voiceUrl),
        fetchOnExpiryCallback: () => get(voiceUrl)
    }),
    speechSynthesizer: new BotChat.Speech.BrowserSpeechSynthesizer({
        fetchCallback: () => get(voiceUrl),
        fetchOnExpiryCallback: () => get(voiceUrl),
        gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Male,
        voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, BenjaminRUS)'
    })
};

botSettings.speechOptions = speechOptions;

BotChat.App(botSettings, document.getElementById("bot"));
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your implementation (don't forget to remove your cognitive key)?

Comment: I've added the code :)

Comment: What do you mean `poor`?  Dose the web chat bot not transfer the speech to text?  Does the `mic` icon have effect when you click it?

Comment: The recognition has very poor quality, light years apart from the recognition in dev.botframework testing panel. Technically, it works, but it doesn't use LUIS priming (in dev.botframework, it does), and I'm even struggling with basic phrases (even 'hi')